# How do you update fields on a table using a form in Microsoft Access via VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 3 columns with titles Used and Add and Total. 
Condition are;

Used: allows user to input any positive value but stores it in the table filed as a negative value.

Add: allows user to input positive values and stores it in the table field as a positive.

Total: Stores the sum of the fields associated with Used and Add.

This is what I have so far. The Total filed does not work as expected. Any idea?

```
'Add to database a new value -------------------------

Private Sub Add_AfterUpdate()

If IsNull(Add.Value) Then
    Add.Value = 0

ElseIf Add.Value < 0 Then
    Add1.Value = -Add.Value

    ElseIf Add.Value > 0 Then
    Add.Value = Add

End If

Total_AfterUpdate 'To update the Total in textbox--------------
Add_Enter 'To show 0 in the textbox--------------


End Sub


'Substract from databae field a new value from already existing value-------


 Private Sub Used_AfterUpdate()

Used.Value = Used
If IsNull(Used.Value) Then
    Used.Value = 0

ElseIf Used.Value < 0 Then
    Used.Value = -Used.Value

    ElseIf Used.Value > 0 Then
    Used.Value = Used

End If


Total_AfterUpdate 'To update the Total in textbox--------------
Add_Enter 'To show 0 in the textbox--------------

End Sub

'Total the results based on changes made through the Used textbox or the Add texbox 

Private Sub Total_AfterUpdate()
Dim TotalAdd As Double
Dim TotalUsed As Double


TotalAdd = Total.Value + Add
Total = TotalAdd
TotalUsed = Total.Value - Used
Total = TotalUsed


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try doing a web search for "How do you update fields on a table using a form in Microsoft Access via VBA"? If so, what about all those results do not apply here?

Comment: Is the form bound to the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add values to fields on a table using forms in Microsoft Access using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269632/how-do-you-add-values-to-fields-on-a-table-using-forms-in-microsoft-access-using)

Comment: Please adjust your original question, or don't edit it to have identical code as this one

Comment: After revising this question makes more sense to me than the previous question. Which has been deleted already.

Comment: Kostas K, Yes the form is bound to the same table and linked up via linked table manage.

Comment: Erik, After revising the previous question, it did not make sense to me so I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, try something like this:

```
Private Sub Used_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNull(Used) Then
        Used = 0
    ElseIf Used > 0 Then
        Used = -Used
    End If
    Total_AfterUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub Add_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNull(Add) Then
        Add = 0
    ElseIf Add < 0 Then
        Add = -Add
    End If
    Total_AfterUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub Total_AfterUpdate()
    Total = Used + Add
End Sub
```

#### **EDIT:** Alternatively, this may be written:

```
Private Sub Used_AfterUpdate()
    Used = -Abs(Nz(Used, 0))
    Total_AfterUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub Add_AfterUpdate()
    Add = Abs(Nz(Add, 0))
    Total_AfterUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub Total_AfterUpdate()
    Total = Used + Add
End Sub
```

Comment: The code updates the filed but does not add Any new values to the already exiting value.

Comment: I don't understand the behaviour you are looking for: the user may enter a value in the `Used` field which will be automatically negated; the user may enter a value in the `Add` field, which will be automatically be made positive. The `Total` field will then display the sum `Used+Add`. What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @WKI, I've edited my answer above to improve the code.

Comment: Sometimes,  the fields Add and Used would already contain values entered by previous user. How would I update this field by adding the new values into the already existing values? A friend has suggested that I create another two columns to temporarily store the values so that vba can refer to it in the background. Say: Inital update: Add=0, Used= 0, Total=0, second update values are added to Add and Used: Add = 12, Used= 2, Total = 10. Third update:  Add = 1, Used = 6 Total should be 5 since this is based on previous values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the code but the Add part is not acting as expected since the used value should subtract a new values from the already exiting Total and the Add part should Add a new value to the already exiting Total.